# How to give static IP in the office and use DHCP at home

Tags: windows, windows-xp, dhcp, static-ip

There is a laptop running Windows XP.

When the computer connects to the Wireless network in the office it should have a static IP address (because it's used as a small DB server).

When it connects to the network anywhere else, it should get its IP using DHCP.

I know about the Alternative IP configuration setting under Windows but in order to use that, I'd have to turn off the DHCP server in the office and assign IPs to each computer manually which I can't do right now.

Any ideas for an easy solution?

---

**Edit:** the computer is at a client's site, access to the router might not be granted. Sorry for not mentioning this before.

What should be my plan B if I can't get access?

Comment: Wait, you have a laptop connected via wireless that you're using as a DB server at work? Really?

Comment: It's the air-db! :-)

Comment: The DB is a Firebird instance with 2 people connecting to it. No need for a server :-)

Answer (score 9):

If you have control over the DHCP server at work, you could assign yourself a static IP by MAC address and use DHCP both at home and at the office.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can go about it. Like katriel said, the easist way would be to add what is usually called a DHCP reservation, where you link your MAC address to an IP address. If this is possible, then it would be the best solution.

You could also write a batch script that sets the IP address manually, but that would have to be launched manually every time you connect to the network.

Finally, you can use 3rd party software, such as the [Mobile Net Switcher](http://www.mobilenetswitch.com/). I have never used it, but it sounds like it would do what you want.

Comment: Could you point me to an example script on setting the IP manually?

Answer (score 1):

Create a reservation for the Laptop on the Wireless DHCP scope.  This way your laptop will always be set to use DHCP but when connected to wireless it will receive a specifically defined IP.